# Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal. The hash literal was incomplete

Tags: powershell

Running a PowerShell script to get printer information from our networked MFDs. PS is returning this error.

```
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; EVENT ID=307}  and The hash literal was incomplete @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; EVENT ID=307} 

$aPrinterList = @()
 
$Results = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; EVENT ID=307} -ComputerName MAHCXXXX
 
 
ForEach($Result in $Results){
  $ProperyData = [xml]$Result.ToXml()
  $PrinterName = $ProperyData.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param5
    
  If($PrinterName.Contains("MAHCXXX")){
    $hItemDetails = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
      DocName = $ProperyData.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param2
      UserName = $ProperyData.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3
      MachineName = $ProperyData.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param4
      PrinterName = $PrinterName
      PageCount = $ProperyData.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param8
      TimeCreated = $Result.TimeCreated
    }
 
    $aPrinterList += $hItemDetails
  }
}
 
#Output results to CSV file
$aPrinterList | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Temp\PrintAudit.csv
```

Looked at all of the code and can't find what I might be missing.

Comment: You have to quote hashtable keys that contain whitespace: `'EVENT ID'=307`

Comment: The correct key is `Id`: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; Id=307}`

Comment: Note that .Contains() is case sensitive.  I would do  `$aPrinterList = foreach(`... instead of the `+=`.